# Bounds involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

Are there any good upper and lower bounds on the following sum or can we simplify this sum to a product of few terms?

$S =\sum_{i=1}^{r-1}{m \choose i}{n \choose r-i}$

where $m, n \gg r.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there $m+n$ fruits of which $m$ are apples and $n$ are oranges. We can choose $r$ fruits from these $m+n$ fruits in $\binom{m+n}{r}$. We can do it by choosing $i$ apples and $r-i$ oranges, for $i=0,1,\cdots,r$. Hence
$$\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum_{i=0}^r\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{r-i}$$
Thus $S=\binom{m+n}{r}-\binom{m}{0}\binom{n}{r}-\binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{0}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!